# Not able to publish custom cloudwatch metric

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch

I am implementing a custom cloudwatch metric for a windows ec2 instance and here's my script for the same. This metric should report cloudwatch regarding the memory and pagefile details.

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetName="credsfromfile", supportsshouldprocess = $true) ]
param(
[switch]$mem_util,
[switch]$mem_used ,
[switch]$mem_avail, 
[switch]$page_used,
[switch]$page_avail,
[switch]$page_util,
[switch]$auto_scale,
[ValidateSet("bytes","kilobytes","megabytes","gigabytes" )]
[string]$memory_units = "none",
[switch]$from_scheduler,
[Parameter(Parametersetname ="credsinline",mandatory=$true)]
[string]$aws_access_id = "",
[Parameter(Parametersetname ="credsinline",mandatory=$true)]
[string]$aws_secret_key = "",
[Parameter(Parametersetname ="credsfromfile")]
[string]$aws_credential_file = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE"),
[string]$logfile = $null,
[Switch]$version
)
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

### Initliaze common variables ###
$accountinfo = New-Object psobject
$wc = New-Object Net.WebClient
$time = Get-Date
[string]$aaid =""
[string]$ask =""
$invoc = (Get-Variable myinvocation -Scope 0).value
$currdirectory = Split-Path $invoc.mycommand.path
$scriptname = $invoc.mycommand.Name
$ver = '1.0.0'
$client_name = 'CloudWatch-PutInstanceDataWindows'
$useragent = "$client_name/$ver"

### Logs all messages to file or prints to console based on from_scheduler setting. ###
function report_message ([string]$message)
{
    if($from_scheduler)
    {   if ($logfile.Length -eq 0 )
        {
            $logfile = $currdirectory +"\" +$scriptname.replace('.ps1','.log')
        }
        $message | Out-File -Append -FilePath $logfile
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host $message
    }
}

### Global trap for all exceptions for this script. All exceptions will exit the script.###
trap [Exception] {
report_message ($_.Exception.Message)
Exit
}
if ($version)
{
 report_message "$scriptname version $ver"
 exit 
}
####Test and load AWS sdk 
$ProgFilesLoc = (${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}, ${env:ProgramFiles} -ne $null)[0]
$SDKLoc = "$ProgFilesLoc\AWS SDK for .NET\bin\Net35"

if ((Test-Path -PathType Container -Path $SDKLoc) -eq $false) {
    $SDKLoc = "C:\Windows\Assembly"
}

$SDKLibraryLocation = dir C:\Windows\Assembly -Recurse -Filter "AWSSDK.dll"
if ($SDKLibraryLocation -eq $null)
{
    throw "Please Install .NET sdk for this script to work."
}
else 
{
    $SDKLibraryLocation = $SDKLibraryLocation.FullName
    Add-Type -Path $SDKLibraryLocation
    Write-Verbose "Assembly Loaded"
}

### Process parameterset for credentials and adds them to a powershell object ###
switch ($PSCmdlet.Parametersetname)
{
    "credsinline" {
                    Write-Verbose "Using credentials passed as arguments"

                    if (!($aws_access_id.Length -eq 0 )) 
                        {
                            $aaid = $aws_access_id
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            throw ("Value of AWS access key id is not specified.")
                        }

                        if (!($aws_secret_key.Length -eq 0 ))
                            {
                                $ask = $aws_secret_key
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                throw "Value of AWS secret key is not specified."
                            }
                    }
    "credsfromfile"{

                    if ( Test-Path $aws_credential_file)
                        {
                            Write-Verbose "Using AWS credentials file $aws_credential_file"
                            Get-Content $aws_credential_file | ForEach-Object { 
                                                            if($_ -match '.*=.*'){$text = $_.split("=");
                                                            switch ($text[0].trim())
                                                            {
                                                                "AWSAccessKeyId"    {$aaid= $text[1].trim()}
                                                                "AWSSecretKey"      { $ask = $text[1].trim()}
                                                            }}}
                        }
                        else {throw "Failed to open AWS credentials file $aws_credential_file"}
                    }   
}
if (($aaid.length -eq 0) -or ($ask.length -eq 0))
{
    throw "Provided incomplete AWS credential set"
}
else 
{

    Add-Member -membertype noteproperty -inputobject $accountinfo -name "AWSSecretKey" -value $ask
    Add-Member -membertype noteproperty -inputobject $accountinfo -name "AWSAccessKeyId" -value $aaid 
    Remove-Variable ask; Remove-Variable aaid
}
### Check if atleast one metric is requested to report.###
if ( !$mem_avail -and !$mem_used -and !$mem_util -and !$page_avail -and !$page_used -and !$page_util)
{
    throw "Please specify a metric to report exiting script" 
}

### Avoid a storm of calls at the beginning of a minute.###
if ($from_scheduler)
{
    $rand = new-object system.random
    start-sleep -Seconds $rand.Next(20)
}

### Functions that interact with metadata to get data required for dimenstion calculation and endpoint for cloudwatch api. ###
function get-metadata {
    $extendurl = $args
    $baseurl = "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data"
    $fullurl = $baseurl + $extendurl
    return ($wc.DownloadString($fullurl))
}

function get-region {
    $az = get-metadata("/placement/availability-zone")
    return ($az.Substring(0, ($az.Length -1)))
}

function get-endpoint {
    $region = get-region
    return "https://monitoring." + $region + ".amazonaws.com/"
}

### Function that creates metric data which will be added to metric list that will be finally pushed to cloudwatch. ###
function append_metric   {
    $metricdata = New-Object Amazon.Cloudwatch.Model.MetricDatum
    $metricdata.metricname, $metricdata.Unit, $metricdata.value, $metricdata.Dimensions = $args
    $metricdata.Timestamp = $time.ToUniversalTime()
    return $metricdata
}

### Function that validates units passed. Default value of  Megabytes is used###
function parse-units {
    param ([string]$mem_units,
        [long]$mem_unit_div)
    $units = New-Object psobject
    switch ($memory_units.ToLower())
                    {
                        "bytes"     {   $mem_units = "Bytes"; $mem_unit_div = 1}
                        "kilobytes" {   $mem_units = "Kilobytes"; $mem_unit_div = 1kb}
                        "megabytes" {   $mem_units = "Megabytes"; $mem_unit_div = 1mb}
                        "gigabytes" {   $mem_units = "Gigabytes"; $mem_unit_div = 1gb}
                        default     {   $mem_units = "Megabytes"; $mem_unit_div = 1mb}
                    }
    Add-Member -InputObject $units -Name "mem_units" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $mem_units
    Add-Member -InputObject $units -Name "mem_unit_div" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $mem_unit_div
    return $units
}

### Function that gets memory stats using WMI###
function get-memory {

begin {}
process {
            $mem = New-Object psobject
            $units = parse-units
            [long]$mem_avail_wmi = (get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | select -expandproperty FreePhysicalMemory) * 1kb
            [long]$total_phy_mem_wmi = get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem |  select -expandproperty TotalPhysicalMemory
            [long]$mem_used_wmi = $total_phy_mem_wmi - $mem_avail_wmi
            Add-Member -InputObject $mem -Name "mem_avail_wmi" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $mem_avail_wmi
            Add-Member -InputObject $mem -Name "total_phy_mem_wmi" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $total_phy_mem_wmi
            Add-Member -InputObject $mem -Name "mem_used_wmi" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $mem_used_wmi
            Add-Member -InputObject $mem -Name "mem_units" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $units.mem_units
            Add-Member -InputObject $mem -Name "mem_unit_div" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $units.mem_unit_div
            write $mem
        }
 end{}
 }

 ### Function that writes metrics to be piped to next fucntion to push to cloudwatch.###
 function create-metriclist {
  param (
        [parameter(Valuefrompipeline=$true)] $mem_info)
 begin{

                        $group_name = ""
                        $instance_id = get-metadata("/instance-id")
                        $auto_scale_group = Get-ASAutoScalingGroup

                        foreach($as in $auto_scale_group)
                        {
                            $flag = 0
                            $group_name = $as.AutoScalingGroupName

                            foreach($ins in $as.Instances)
                            {
                                Write-Host $ins.InstanceId
                                Write-Host "`r`n"
                                if ($ins.InstanceId -eq $instance_id)
                                {
                                    $flag = 1
                                    break
                                }
                            }

                            if ($flag -eq 1)
                            {
                                break
                            }
                            Write-Host "---------------------------`r`n"                      
                        }

                        Write-Host $instance_id
                        Write-Host "`r`n"
                        Write-Host $group_name
                        Write-Host "`r`n"

            $dimlist = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[Amazon.Cloudwatch.Model.Dimension]
                        $dims = New-Object Amazon.Cloudwatch.Model.Dimension

                        if ( $auto_scale)
                        {
                            $dims.Name = "AutoScalingGroupName"
                            $dims.value = $group_name
                        }
                        else
                        {
                $dims.Name = "InstanceId"
                $dims.value = $instance_id
                        }


            $dimlist.Add($dims)

            $pagefilessize = @{}
            $pagefileusage = @{}

            gwmi Win32_PageFileSetting | ForEach-Object{$pagefilessize[$_.name]=$_.MaximumSize *1mb}
            gwmi Win32_PageFileUsage | ForEach-Object{$pagefileusage[$_.name]=$_.currentusage *1mb}
            [string[]]$pagefiles = $pagefilessize.keys

        }
 process{
            if ($mem_util)
                        {
                            $percent_mem_util= 0
                            if ( [long]$mem_info.total_phy_mem_wmi -gt 0 ) { $percent_mem_util = 100 * ([long]$mem_info.mem_used_wmi/[long]$mem_info.total_phy_mem_wmi)}
                            write (append_metric "MemoryUtilization" "Percent"  ("{0:N2}" -f $percent_mem_util) $dimlist)
                        }
            if ($mem_used)
                        {
                            write (append_metric "MemoryUsed" $mem_info.mem_units ("{0:N2}" -f ([long]($mem_info.mem_used_wmi/$mem_info.mem_unit_div))) $dimlist)
                        }
            if ( $mem_avail) 
                        {
                            write (append_metric "MemoryAvailable" $mem_info.mem_units ("{0:N2}" -f ([long]($mem_info.mem_avail_wmi/$mem_info.mem_unit_div))) $dimlist)
                        }
            if ($page_avail)
                {
                    for ($i=0; $i -le ($pagefiles.count - 1);$i++)
                        {   
                            write (append_metric ("pagefileAvailable("+$pagefiles[$i]+")") $mem_info.mem_units ("{0:N2}" -f ((($pagefilessize[$pagefiles[$i]]- ($pagefileusage[$pagefiles[$i]]))/$mem_info.mem_unit_div))) $dimlist)        
                        }
                }
                if ($page_used)
                {
                    for ($i = 0; $i -le ($pagefiles.count -1); $i++)
                    {
                        write (append_metric ("pagefileUsed("+$pagefiles[$i]+")") $mem_info.mem_units ("{0:N2}" -f (($pagefileusage[$pagefiles[$i]])/$mem_info.mem_unit_div)) $dimlist)
                    }
                }
                if ($page_util)
                {
                    for ($i=0; $i -le ($pagefiles.count -1);$i++)
                    {
                        if($pagefilessize[$pagefiles[$i]] -gt 0 )
                        {
                            write (append_metric ("pagefileUtilization("+$pagefiles[$i]+")") "Percent" ("{0:N2}" -f((($pagefileusage[$pagefiles[$i]])*100)/$pagefilessize[$pagefiles[$i]])) $dimlist)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
 end{}

 }
 ### Uses AWS sdk to push metrics to cloudwathc. This finally prints a requestid.###
 function put-instancemem {
 param (
        [parameter(Valuefrompipeline=$true)] $metlist)
 begin{
        $cwconfig = New-Object Amazon.CloudWatch.AmazonCloudWatchConfig
        $cwconfig.serviceURL = get-endpoint
        $cwconfig.UserAgent = $useragent
        $monputrequest  = new-object Amazon.Cloudwatch.Model.PutMetricDataRequest
        $response = New-Object psobject
        $metricdatalist = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[Amazon.Cloudwatch.Model.MetricDatum]

    }
 process{
            if ($PSCmdlet.shouldprocess($metlist.metricname,"The metric data "+$metlist.value.tostring() +" "+ $metlist.unit.tostring()+" will be pushed to cloudwatch")){
            $metricdatalist.add($metlist)
            Write-Verbose ("Metricname= " +$metlist.metricname+" Metric Value= "+ $metlist.value.tostring()+" Metric Units= "+$metlist.unit.tostring())
            }

        }
 end{
        $monputrequest.namespace = "System/Windows" 
        if ($metricdatalist.count -gt 0 ) {
                $cwclient = New-Object Amazon.Cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClient($accountinfo.AWSAccessKeyId,$accountinfo.AWSSecretKey,$cwconfig)
                $monputrequest.metricdata = $metricdatalist
                $monresp =  $cwclient.PutMetricData($monputrequest)
                Add-Member -Name "RequestId" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $monresp.ResponseMetadata.RequestId -InputObject $response

            }
            else {throw "No metric data to push to CloudWatch exiting script" }
        Write-Verbose ("RequestID: " +  $response.RequestId)
    }
 }

 ### Pipelined call of fucntions that pushs metrics to cloudwatch.
 get-memory | create-metriclist | put-instancemem
```

When I execute this manually, I am getting an output as shown below:

```
'UserAgent' is a ReadOnly property.
```

But when I try `get-memory | create-metriclist` it is giving me the full details of memory and pagefile. Which means something is going wrong while trying to push to cloudwatch.

Can someone help me?

Comment: It looks like the error may relate to line ~324 `$cwconfig.UserAgent = $useragent`.  I agree the [UserAgent documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/P_Amazon_Runtime_ClientConfig_UserAgent.htm) says this is get/set, but I also get that error in practice when I try to assign a UserAgent value (also see `$cwconfig | Get-Member UserAgent`).  I'm not aware of how the CW client's UA is used, what are you trying to get from that?

Comment: FYI, see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-monitoring-scripts-for-microsoft-windows/  Also, Ec2Config can do similar: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_WinAMI.html#send_logs_to_cwl